# XSLT split string to create select option

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to create an dropdown element in an XSLT where the value and label is separated by a colon (:) and a newline for the next item.

1st I have a plain xml like; (system generated)

```
<root>
<item>
test1 : Test 1
test2 : Test 2
test3 : Test 3
</item>
</root>
```

then I split it to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="text/text()" name="tokenize">

        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="separator" select="'&#x0a;'"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
                <item><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/></item>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <item>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
                </item>

                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>

            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
<text>
<item>test1 : Test 1</item>
<item>test2 : Test 2</item>
<item>test3 : Test 3</item>
</text>
</root>
```

Then I don't know what's next? Is it possible to create a second template to create the html select?

```
<select>
<option value="test1">Test 1</option>
<option value="test2">Test 2</option>
<option value="test3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Please helppppp.... :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you change your stylesheet to something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <select>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </select>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'&#10;'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <option value="{substring-before($token, ' : ')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($token, ' : ')"/>
            </option>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you will receive:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <select>
         <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
         <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
         <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
      </select>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! that's quick! You save my day sir! Kudos!